# Nested Cursors in MySQL Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, nested-loops, cursors

I need to iterate through a particular table for some conditions.On that conditions it will return a list of row data,which i need to delete in the procedure,but the data is linked with multiple other tables so what I thought to do is to get the primary key of the fetched rows in one cursor and concatenate it with comma in my first iteration and with that concatenated list I can do one query to fetch datas from linked tables (using FIND_IN_SET function)...

I tried something like this which is not working as expected...Can anyone please tell me whether this can be possible to do or to do in anyother way...

Here in this example,
                                                                                                                            There are two tables scmn_sop_dtls and scmn_sop_addnl_dtls,these two tables have foreign key relation with one column so,what i'm trying to do is i'll fetch some details from scmn_sop_dtls and insert into record table and the one i'm inserting i need to delete in scmn_sop_dtls table.So when i delete it is throwing foreign key relation error since it is linked with scmn_sop_addnl_dtls.So first i need to collect all the sopid and concatenated into list and that list i'm passing to the second cursor to fetch that particular row from child table(scmn_sop_addnl_dtls). but it is not fetching them.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `scmn_nov21`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `MoveSampleData`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `MoveSampleData`()
BEGIN
Block1: BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE par_sop_id VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE par_sop_addnl_id VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE sopdl_sop_id_list VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE sopdl_sop_param_list VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE sopdl_temp_sop_param_list VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE sopdl_temp_sop_id VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE c_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT sop_id FROM scmn_sop_dtls WHERE created_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
OPEN c_1;
REPEAT
FETCH c_1 INTO par_sop_id;
INSERT INTO record VALUES(par_sop_id,"Sub","Sop data","NIL",0,NOW());
  SET sopdl_temp_sop_id = CONCAT(par_sop_id, ',');
       SET sopdl_sop_id_list = CONCAT(sopdl_sop_id_list, sopdl_temp_sop_id);
Block2: BEGIN
DECLARE done2 INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE c_2 CURSOR FOR SELECT sop_addnl_id FROM scmn_sop_addnl_dtls WHERE FIND_IN_SET(sop_id,sopdl_sop_id_list);
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done2 = 1;
OPEN c_2;
REPEAT
FETCH c_2 INTO par_sop_addnl_id;
INSERT INTO record_arc VALUES(par_sop_addnl_id,"Sub","Sop data","NIL",0,NOW());
UNTIL done2 END REPEAT;
CLOSE c_2;
END Block2;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE c_1;
END Block1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Lots of detail - can you simplify with table details?

Comment: I'm new to procedures..It would be really very helpful if someone helps...:)

Comment: sopdl_sop_id_list defaults to null - and concatenating anything to null results in null.

Comment: Does scmn_sop_addnl_dtls have ON DELETE CASCADE on the foreign key constraint?

Comment: @P.Salmon How to set that variable to an empty string?

Comment: A nested cursor loop looks like a bad idea since you will enter block 2 more often than is probably necessary.

Comment: yes it is having an foreign key constraint

Comment: Not what I asked.

Comment: I should change the whole way of writing my pocedure right You asked about foreign key constraint right?

Comment: I would say so and you could strip the data to its simplest level so you can see how this stuff works and  use the record table to assist in debugging.

Comment: I didn't ask if the foreign key constraint existed I  asked if it had an ON DELETE CASCADE clause

Comment: Ok I'll try now thanks for your help...:)

Comment: Thanks for your help the problem is my string variable was null and that's why i'm not getting any values fetched...After i changed the declaration it worked as expected...